# Entity Framework log any errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, exception, log4net

What's the best practice to log any appearing errors caused by Entity Framework?

Currently I'm using log4net, but I think this is independent to the logging framework.

Regarding an example API:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Test> GetTests()
    {
        using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            return context.Tests.Where(w=>w.Enabled).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

For now, I would have to stick my method body in a try/catch (and I'd have to stick all method bodies of all controllers in try/catch blocks)

```
try
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return context.Tests.Where(w=>w.Enabled).ToList();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // TODO: handle also those ValidationErrors, thrown by Entity Framework
    // so here we get a lot more code
    _logger.Error(e);
}
```

But I don't want to put any method body of my API in a try/catch block.

Is there a possibility like adding an `OnException` in my `DatabaseContext` class, where I always can log any exception thrown by Entity Framework?

Comment: check 3rd type of exception handling in http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1068/aspnet-mvc-exception-handling

Comment: @PranavPatel haha, this page really looks like curry... you mean that `HandleErrorAttribute`?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Yes you add that to the global filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the following:

[Global Error Handling in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling)

[Exception Filters](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling)

To take things even further, if you want to get detailed information about what is going on with the underlying commands, you can implement an [Interceptor](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx) as well.

Comment: the combination of exception filter and the interceptor-implementation fits perfectly me needs. Thx!